# Upload multiple files in array of objects with multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I build the exam demo with multiple questions like this

```
[{
 image: an_image_file,
 audio: audio_file,
 text: just_text,
 another_text: text
}]
```

The problem is I can't handle upload file with multer because the image files and audio files are in an array of object per question.

Here is my frontend code:

```js
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const form = new FormData();
    data.questions.forEach((question, index) => {
      form.append(`questions[${index}].img`, question.img);
      form.append(`questions[${index}].audio`, question.audio);
      form.append(`questions[${index}].text`, question.text);
    });
    try {
      const result = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:1445/api/v1/exam',
        form
      );
      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {}
  };
```

It works if I use `upload.any()` but it seems not good for security. Please let me know how to handle this.

Upadte #1:
Here is my backend code:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const compression = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use('*', cors());
app.use(compression());

const upload = multer({
  limits: 100000000,

  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log(__dirname);
      const dir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public');
      if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
      }
      cb(null, dir);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log('body', req.body);
      cb(null, `${date}_${file.filename}`);
    },
  }),
});

const router = express.Router();
const api = router.post(
  '/exam/',
  upload.any(),
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    return res.json({ ok: 'ok' });
  }
);
```

Comment: You need to share the server side code as well.

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu I updated backend code

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `upload.any` is not good for security?

Can you not do something like this?

```
const upload = multer({
  ... // current options,
  fileFilter
});

const expectedMimetypes = [...];

function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
  // write your logic here to determine of the file
  // is of one of the types that you expect
  // You can do that using "file.mimetype"
  const accept = expectedMimetypes.indexOf(file.mimetype) !== -1;
  callback(null, accept); 
}
```